# Error:Connection to http://192.xxx.xxx.xx:8080 refused

Tags: android, web-services, http

I am trying to hit a webservice from my android code. Sometimes it gets hit properly but many of the times it gives above error. The system on which the webservice is deployed is connected to wifi. And my device is also using the same wifi. In short we both are using same network. Still experiencing this issue. The webservices are getting hit from browser everytime.

Comment: try change http to http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 , if it still doesn't work probably you must setting the web server

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat changing ip doesnot work

Comment: Did you forwarded your ip from wifi router to laptop's port?
and i assume that 192.xxx... it's local ip of wifi router not the laptop right?

Comment: `The webservices are getting hit from browser everytime.`. From the browser on your device you mean?